# Restrict cloudwatch access by region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

[I can't use a resource arn to restrict cloudwatch access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/iam-access-control-overview-cw.html).

But I can use conditions. Can I use a condition to only allow users to perform cloudwatch actions in a specific region? I haven't seen any examples of using conditions like this.

Answer (score 2):

CloudWatch is very bad in terms of access control as it does not provide either resources to use in 'Resources' or condition Keys. At some point the DescribeAlarms action in particular was being performed on a US region and was causing unwanted errors when accessing through the console, but I don't see in my CloudTrail that it does now. Maybe it can be restricted to all actions now.

A policy statement to restrict cloudwatch access to the eu-central-region would be:

```
         {
           "Sid": "CloudWatchInFrankfurtOnly",
           "Effect": "Deny",
           "NotAction": ["cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms"],
           "Resource": ["arn:aws:cloudwatch:*:*:alarm:*","arn:aws:cloudwatch::*:dashboard/*"],
           "Condition": {"StringNotEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": "eu-central-1"}}
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use conditions in your policy, for example the below policy will only allow access to cloudwatch actions in eu-central-1.

```
{
        "Statement": [
            {    "Sid": "Stmt1338559372809",


                 "Action": [
             "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
             "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
             "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms"
              ],

                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:Region": "eu-central-1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
  }
```

Hope it will Help!

Comment: But ec2 region will only let it interact with EC2 resources won't it? Why are you using ec2: region?

Comment: It will not make a difference, as you already given access of cloudwatch now you just applying a filter for  region. try it .. if its not working let me know

Comment: @ShashiBhushan did *you* try it?  There are two apparent problems, here.  First, an `allow` policy statement is **never** correctly described as a "filter."  If one policy grants both X and Y and another policy grants only Y, then you still have both X and Y.  The existence of "allow Y" does not implicitly deny X when X is already allowed.  Also, the `ec2:region` condition context key is documented as being service-specific to EC2 and should do nothing here.

Comment: yeah this does not work. Cloudwatch is region specific though, is there really no way to control access?